# Change working directory of glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

How can I change the working directory of glassfish from domains/domain1/config to my WebAPP directory such as WEB-INF/myfiles

Comment: for what you need this can you explain, so that we can suggest you solution better

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on current working directory being set to anywhere in a Java EE application.

You can, however, ask the JVM for where a given resource is physically located, and go from there.

If this is for log files, I've found that it works the best for us if our log statements end up in java.util.logging and then let Glassfish manage them.